# How to show only customer invoice or supplier invoice on form views?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

In odoo 10.0, I have added a field `invoice_id`:

```python
invoice_id = fields.Many2one('account.invoice', 'Invoice', domain=[('state','=','open')])
```

I want to show this field on two views: one view for customer and other one for supplier.

Now I'd like to show in this field only customer invoices for the customer form view and supplier invoice for the supplier form view.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to filter the invoices for a specific user go to the invoices view, filter by `open` invoices and then filter by writing the customer as well. You can even create a button to show the open invoices, you should return the action window with the right domain.

In fact, I think there is already a button to show the invoiced invoices, maybe you need to activate it on the accounting settings.

But setting aside all of this and getting to the point, you could add a domain in the field for each form view:

**Customer view:**

```xml
<field name="invoice_id" domain="[('type','=','out_invoice')]" />
```

**Supplier view:**

```xml
<field name="invoice_id" domain="[('type','=','in_invoice')]" />
```

**Note**: possible values for `type`

```
type = fields.Selection(
    string='Type',
    selection=[
        ('out_invoice', 'Customer Invoice'),
        ('in_invoice', 'Supplier Invoice'),
        ('out_refund', 'Customer Refund'),
        ('in_refund', 'Supplier Refund')
    ],
)
```

Comment: Moreover if you want to see all invoices, you can have One2many field.

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to show also invoices with state open. But the problem in my new model I don't have type and state fields, so the domain works only if the fields are decalared in the current view

Comment: Would you like to show all the invoices as @ajay says? You already are using the domain on the field in the python side to filter only the open invoices, which is right. If you want to bring a field from other model you can created a [related field](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#related-fields).

Comment: I have added more information at the beggining of my answer, check if it clarifies anything.